# Laravel on 1and1 server

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, http-status-code-403

I have a 1&1 WebServer unlimited, and I am trying to put my new Laravel (latest version) project via FTP inside a subfolder (called `v2`) of this server.

When accessing my website like that: `www.mywebsite.com/v2/` I am getting the following:

> Error 403 - Forbidden
>
> L'accès au fichier requiert une autorisation.
>     (this is french, it means we are not authorized to access the file)

I have tried changing the file permission on `v2` and all subfolders to `777`, but nothing changed.

I suspect the default Laravel `.htaccess` to be a problem on 1&1 servers.

Here it is:

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone already got this issue and managed to fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create virtualhost and point it to /v2/public folder. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName v2.mywebsite.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/path_to_your_v2_folder/public"
  <Directory "/home/path_to_your_v2_folder/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After restarting Apache, you'll be able to use Laravel on v2.mywebsite.com

Update:

Maybe you have some kind of control panel software? Or maybe 1&1 support will add virtualhost for you?

Also, there is little bit ugly, but working solution. For example, if you have access to `userhome` (just an example) directory in which you have `public_html` or `www` or other folder for your website. So, just install your Laravel project in that `userhome` directory and create `symbolic link` pointed from Laravel's `public` directory to `public_html/v2/` or `www/v2`. You can do it if you have access to a server through SFTP or SSH protocols. If you have only FTP (which is weird in our days), you will not be able to create symbolic links.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the server configuration, it's a ready to use web server

Comment: Thanks for your help Alexey.
I managed to get it working by changing 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
to 
RewriteRule ^ /v2/public/index.php [L]
On my .htaccess file (that is inside public folder)

But problem is that to access my website it need to do:
www.mywebsite.com/v2/public/
instead of just:
www.mywebsite.com/v2/